# How can I cast List<Object> to List<Foo> when foo is a type variable and I don't know the type

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I have a situation where through reflection I have List>object<. I also have a reflected method that takes List>foo<. List>object< contains a whole bunch of foos, but List>object< cannot be directly casted to List>foo<. I have a Type variable that contains foo, but do not know it at compile time. My code looks something like below

```
var ASM = Assembly.LoadFrom("foo.dll");
var bar = List<string>() { /*A whole bunch of string literals*/ };

var FooType = ASM.GetType("Foo")
List<object> foos = new List<object>; 
foreach (var str in bar)
{
   foos.add(Activator.CreateInstance(FooType, new [] {str}));
}

var Flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFalgs.Public;
FooType.GetMethod("DoSomethingWithAListOfFoo", Flags).Invoke(null, foos)
```

At this point I'm told that a List cannot be converted to a List via a runtime exception

Comment: I made a slight modification to your code to correct what looked like typos. Can you please confirm it's ok?

Comment: Do you actually mean List<Object> or are you referring to a List<T> where the type is unknown?

Comment: I'm wondering if the is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in this question. Even if you are able to "cast" the list, the reference to the list will be of type `object`. What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: @JohnWu in reflection it's not uncommon to get an object back from a reflected method, then just pass that object into another reflected method. For instance the "DoSomethingWithAListOfFoo" would take a List<Foo> but because of reflection you can pass in an array of objects and it accepts a List<Foo> type even if it is an object.

Comment: @Sidney: In that scenario, you *do* know the type at compile time. You know you need a `List<Foo>`. Otherwise how do you even know to call `DoSomethingWithAListOfFoo` at all?

Comment: @JohnWu What if for some reason you don't want to include the DLL that contains defines Foo?

Comment: @Sidney I understand now, thank you. I've added an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Reflection go you into this mess, so you're going to need reflection to get you out, only it's going to be deeper darker nastier reflection. Reflection of Generic Methods.

---

So lets say you've aleady got your foos variable populated. It's a list of objects. How do you cast a list of something to a list of something else? Cast!
In your instance, you want Cast but you don't have access to that from what I understand, so we need to create an instance of the Cast method. First we need to get the Generic Cast method

```
var GenericCastMethod = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
  .GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Now we need to make a type specific cast method

```
var SpecificCastMethod = GenericCastMethod.MakeGenericMethod(FooType);
```

Finally, we need to call this on your list

```
var FoosOfTypeFoo = SpecificCastMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { foos });
```

You can now use FoosOfTypeFoo *as an IEnumerable*. This if of course, not what you want. So we need to do the same thing on ToList method. Sparing you the gory details, all put together it should look like this

```
var GenericCastMethod = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
  .GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var SpecificCastMethod = GenericCastMethod.MakeGenericMethod(FooType);
var IEnumerableOfFoo = SpecificCastMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { foos });

var GenericToListMethod = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
  .GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var SpecificToListMethod = GenericToListMethod .MakeGenericMethod(FooType);
var ListOfFoo = SpecificToListMethod .Invoke(null, new object[] { FoosOfTypeFoo });
```

---

The moral of this story is that black magic code begets fouler darker black magic code.

Comment: I like how this is written like you are about to summon some sort of demon.

Comment: @IanH.You know, considering my code contains `using ⛧.Reflection` :)

Answer (score 1):

### Don't use Reflection, use an ArrayList (no, really)

Do you remember the old type, `ArrayList`? Nobody uses it much any more; it's just like `List<object>`. But there is one key difference: ArrayList has a `ToArray(Type)` method (not a `ToArray<T>` method, since generics didn't exist back then). So you easily can make an array with any type, as long as you can get a `Type` object for them.

Here are two solutions that take advantage of this feature.

**Solution 1. One line change.**

If `DoSomethingWithAListOfFoos`accepts an `IEnumerable<Foo>` (and doesn't require it to be a `List<Foo>`), you can just use this:

```
FooType.GetMethod("DoSomethingWithAListOfFoo", Flags)
    .Invoke(
        null, 
        new ArrayList(foos).ToArray(FooType)  //Magic!!!
    );
```

Easy enough, right? You didn't even have to reflect anything.

**Solution 2. Extension method.**

If `DoSomethingWithAListOfFoos` truly requires a `List<Foo>` we have a little more work to do because we have to construct the generic list.

First, add this extension method somewhere in your code:

```
static public ICollection ToGenericList(this ICollection input, Type itemType)
{
    return (ICollection) typeof(List<>)
        .MakeGenericType(itemType)
        .InvokeMember(
            null, 
            BindingFlags.CreateInstance, 
            null, 
            null, 
            new object[] { new ArrayList(input).ToArray(itemType) }
        );
}
```

This works because every `List<T>` comes with a constructor that will accept an array. And we already figured out how to make the array very easily. We just locate the right constructor and pass it in, and the runtime does the rest.

Now just call it like this:

```
FooType.GetMethod("DoSomethingWithAListOfFoo", Flags)
    .Invoke(
        null, 
        new foos.ToGenericList(FooType)   //Our new extension method
    );
```